# javascript library to perspective distort a drawing

Tags: drawing, javascript, distortion

I have a drawing with several lines inside it and I need to animate it moving it and at the same time trasforming it from a rectangle to a parallelogram, as in the toy example image below. I wonder if there are any libraries which can perform such operations without the need to write down a complex and inefficient routine by myself. I am ready to use some graphic libraries as d3, Raphael or Highcharts which I already know a bit, but I don't know if they have a routine such the one I have described. What's the easiest thing to do?
[image: example]

Comment: Please explain your downvote, so I can make my question better and clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Raphael just apply a matrix, I show you an example made with a set of 2 different types of draws:

```
var R = Raphael(10,150,200,140);
var r = R.rect(0,0,200,100).attr({fill: "red"});
var p = R.path("M0,50h200");
var s = R.set();
s.push(r);
s.push(p);
s.transform("m1,0.2,0,1,0,0");
```

The second value is the X skew, it will skew a fraction of the element width.

And is the same with inline svg.

```
<svg width="200" height="140" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#00f" stroke="#000" transform="matrix(1,0.2,0,1,0,0)">
    </rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/mjthxpok/

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I've not been very clear. Your example works well in static mode. I need to animate the transition from the rectangle to the parallelogram. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok, made by myself: http://jsfiddle.net/aonj42xy/. Thank you for sketching the solution.